# Javascript press keycode "+1 enter" and "-1 enter"

Tags: javascript, keycode

Does anybody know how to detect pressing keycode "+1 enter" and "-1 enter" in Javascript, please.
I would like to detect when pressing keycodes ONE BY ONE rather than at one time.

But when I wrote the following codes, no effect was given.

```
// +1 enter
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 107 && e.keyCode == 49 && e.keyCode == 13) {
    window.alert("+1");
    }
});

// -1 enter
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 109 && e.keyCode == 49 && e.keyCode == 13) {
    window.alert("-1");
    }
});
```

For your professional comments, please.

Comment: You should be using `||`, not `&&`. How can a single keypess be 3 different characters at the same time?

Comment: I mean pressing +, 1, enter or - , 1, enter one by one but in short time

Comment: Are you open to libraries that implement what you're looking for (key sequences), or are you needing to stick to vanilla JS and jQuery?

Comment: I have tested your suggestion, but it is not correct. When I pressed +/-, 1 or enter, the window would be prompted.

Comment: jdphenix, I shall follow jQuery, I think.

Comment: Not able to write a full answer right now, but you could set variables to see if a key was pressed and use a timeout to clear the variables if another is not pressed within a certain timeframe. Ie, if key + is pressed set var1 to 1, then when 1 is pressed check if var1 == 1 and set var2 to 1, then when enter is pressed check if var2 == 1 and perform an action.

Answer (score 0):

In order to accomplish this, you need to be able to keep track of previous keys pressed. Try the following:

```js
// These are just used to display the result in the DOM--you can delete this
var $keyCodes = document.getElementById('key-codes');
var $result = document.getElementById('result');

// Used to keep track of your key presses
var trackKeyCodes = (function() {
  // Keep a private array of key codes to track
  var keyCodes = [];
  // This is the actual function that gets stored in trackKeyCodes
  return function(keyCode) {
    // Only store the last 3 key codes
    if (keyCodes.length === 3) keyCodes.splice(0, 1);
    // Add the next key code
    keyCodes.push(keyCode);
    // This just displays it in the DOM for you to see--you can delete this
    $keyCodes.innerHTML = keyCodes.join(', ');
    return keyCodes;
  };
})();
// Used to actually check the key presses
var checkKeyCodes = function(keyCodes, first, second, third) {
  return keyCodes[0] === first && keyCodes[1] === second && keyCodes[2] === third;
};

// +1 enter
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  var keyCodes = trackKeyCodes(e.keyCode);
  if (checkKeyCodes(keyCodes, 107, 49, 13)) {
      $result.innerHTML = '+ 1';
  } else if (checkKeyCodes(keyCodes, 109, 49, 13)) {
      $result.innerHTML = '- 1';
  } else {
      $result.innerHTML = '';
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
KeyCodes: <span id="key-codes">-</span>
</p>
<p>
Result: <span id="result">-</span>
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks. But where should the code "window.alert" be put in your codes? And also what does your code mean?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following function:

```
$(document).keydown((function() {
    var codes = [];
    return function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 107 || e.keyCode == 109 || e.keyCode == 49 || e.keyCode == 13) {
            codes.push(e.keyCode);
            if (codes.toString().indexOf('107,49,13') >= 0) {
                alert('+1');
                codes.splice(0, codes.length);
            } else if (codes.toString().indexOf('109,49,13') >= 0) {
                alert('-1');
                codes.splice(0, codes.length);
            }
        } else {
            codes.splice(0, codes.length);
        }
    };
})());
```

Basically, you just have to find some way of storing previously pressed keys, and then checking them each time a new key is pressed. In this case it's stored in a variable within the closure of an IIFE.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wdaq8tdt/1/).

Comment: @CKH yes it does, you will have to click on the lower-right box and use the numpad `+` and `-` keys.

Comment: No, when I pressed num lock, and press + or -, 1 and enter one by one, no alert window was prompted.

Comment: @CKH you will need to use the normal `1` key and not the num pad one. I'm just using the keyCodes you posted in your original question - that corresponds to the keyboard `1`. Change the keyCodes if this doesn't suit your needs.